# How to reset region center when exited region in background using CoreLocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager, region-monitoring

My idea is simple in theory, but am having a really hard time executing it.  I want to create a geofence at the user's location, and when the user exits that region, I want to recenter the region at the user's updated location.  Here is the flow:

1. Retrieve user's currently location using standard [CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation]
2. On locationManager:didUpdateLocations:, create a geofence at the current location using startMonitoringForRegion, and on subsequent location updates, recenter that region
3. On locationManager:didExitRegion:, which is usually called from the background to wake up the app, call [CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation] to retrieve the user's current location to recenter the geofence (centered to the next updated location that is NOT the current region center coordinate).

Sometimes this all works, but more often than not, the geofence doesn't recenter correctly.  What's been happening is that the region is re-centered and locationManager:didExitRegion: is immediately called, which puts it into an infinite loop until the app is terminated again. Since it is terminated without a valid monitored region, the app then won't be woken up for location updates.

Is this incorrect usage of region monitoring?  I'm trying to play with different ways of tracking user location in a battery efficient way (and not constantly using the standard startUpdatingLocation).  Would a combination of signification location change tracking and visit monitoring be more effective?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is it will be hard to be more efficient at tracking user location than Apple. I don't know why you're getting the infinite loop (code sample would help) but it doesn't seem like an appropriate use of geofencing to me. Can you describe a little more what your use case is? It sounds interesting.

Comment: I agree that it's probably a fool's errand to try to be more efficient at tracking than Apple. That's also the same point that all the WWDC videos on CoreLocation try to make, too. The use case is that the app will track the user's path for live path logging (so no deferred updates), but the user can choose to leave it on for days at a time, so battery efficiency is obviously very important. I have the standard monitoring to pause automatically, but after that want to find ways to wake up the app to log points.